# R: Gamma GLM assumption testing

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, heteroscedasticity, assumptions, gamma-distribution

Can I still run a gamma GLM in R if my data does not pass the equal variance assumption through the Levene Test? Is there a nonparametric test I should run instead or can I just run the gamma GLM?

Answer (score 4):

Gamma glm's do not have an assumption of constant variance. Generalized linear models have a specific **variance function**, depending on the family.  What you need to look for is if the residual variance conforms to your models variance function. [Details for gamma glm's here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_function#Example_%E2%80%93_Gamma).  So the Levene test for constant variance is irrelevant!

Some relevant posts with details:

- [What are the assumptions of a Gamma GLM or GLMM for hypothesis testing?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390063/what-are-the-assumptions-of-a-gamma-glm-or-glmm-for-hypothesis-testing)
- [Help understanding parameterization of gamma distribution in R's glm()](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/509477/help-understanding-parameterization-of-gamma-distribution-in-rs-glm)
- [Testing the variance part of a Generalized Linear Model out of sample?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112219/testing-the-variance-part-of-a-generalized-linear-model-out-of-sample)

For an informal check on the variance function, you can plot the absolute residuals against the predicted value